# determine the maximum cross‐sectional area.

Tags: calculus, optimization

The client wants to maximise the volume of a materials store to be constructed next to a 3  metre high stone wall (shown as OA in the cross section in the diagram). The roof (AB) and  front (BC) are to be constructed from corrugated metal sheeting. Only 6 metre length sheets  are available. Each of them is to be cut into two parts such that one part is used for the roof  and the other is used for the front. Find the dimensions x and y of the store that will  maximise  the  cross‐sectional  area  and  therefore  the  volume.  Hence  determine  the  maximum cross‐sectional area. [image: Problem in image]

Comment: Please help! This assignment is due tomorrow!

Comment: Can you give a picture ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo The image has been added

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

By Pythagoras find $y$ as a function of $x$ (squaring the constraint side by side) and then optimize the area as a function of $x$.